# MYSQL Trigger Not Working. Not sure why

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger for my table named quailmiles.  When the total miles hits a certain number I want the persons status (which is a attribute in that same table) to change.  For some reason my code is not working.

The error currently reads:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER status_update 
AFTER UPDATE ON quailmiles
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (total_miles > 2000) THEN
    UPDATE quailmiles SET status = 'gold';
ELSE IF (total_miles > 4000) THEN
    UPDATE quailmiles SET status = 'platinum';
END IF;
END $$
delimiter;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is backwards.  You need to test against `4000` before `2000`:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER status_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON qualmiles
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.total_miles > 4000) THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'platinum';
    ELSEIF (NEW.total_miles > 2000) THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'gold';
    END IF;
END $$
delimiter;
```

I also changed the syntax to be a "before" update trigger.  Also, I made the name "qualmiles".  "Quailmiles" sounds funny.

Comment: I tried your code and there still seems to be an error....#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

Comment: @user3723302, error is in last line `delimiter;`. add a space. It should be `delimiter ;`

Comment: @Rahul: the subsequent DELIMITER statement isn't part of the trigger, and it's not causing the error. Gordon just missed removing the space in **`ELSE IF`**. (Gordon also fixed some of the bigger problems in the trigger.)

Comment: +1. As Gordon points out, this really does need to be a BEFORE UPDATE trigger. I'd change the conditions to check **`NEW.total_miles`** rather than just **`total_miles`**. And remove the space in **`ELSE IF`**. Gordon's got the right approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want **`ELSEIF`** rather than **`ELSE IF`**.  (Remove the space.)

The error is being returned because that second `IF` isn't being ended with an `END IF`.

Also, you don't really want to issue an UPDATE against the same table. You'd rather this be handled in a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, and set the value of the column.

e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER status_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON quailmiles
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.total_miles > 4000) THEN
      SET NEW.status = 'platinum';
   ELSIF (NEW.total_miles > 2000) THEN
      SET NEW.status = 'gold';
   END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: Nope, error is in last line `delimiter;`. needs a space between `delimiter` and `;`

Comment: @Rahul: There is definitely an error in the `IF` syntax, the second `IF` isn't being ended with an `END IF`, that's the source of the #1064 error. There are a lot of other errors... attempting to UPDATE the same table, and doing it without any predicates (i.e. updating ALL rows in the table). A failure of a subsequent `DELIMITER` statement doesn't cause an error in the trigger definition.

Comment: Yes, overlooked that but don't say subsequent DELIMITER statement will not cause error. Unless you haven't included the `delimiter` ... the last line will always throw 1064 syntax error. can bet on it.

Comment: @spencer7593 so when you update the same table you need to update all the rows?

Comment: @user3723302: A TRIGGER is not allowed to modify the same table that is being used by the statement that fired the trigger. Within the trigger, it's not possible to issue an `UPDATE` statement against the same table. And even if it were allowed, the `UPDATE` statement in your trigger doesn't have a `WHERE` clause; if that `UPDATE` statement were allowed to execute, it would modify ALL rows in the table, and set the value of the `status` column on all rows.